# where html blade functions are written in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i looked into laravel helper classes but i didn't found the where is written blade template built in functions like

```
 @extends()
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: in laravel 5.1 that should be in laravel collective, http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html

Comment: yup, look at laravelcollective, has been removed from the laravel (core) framework

Answer (score 0):

check in your project directory ,for example in my case

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\project1\vendor\illuminate\html
```

in that directory you will see FormBuilder.php class.in that they declared

for form close

```
 public function close()
    {
        $this->labels = array();

        $this->model = null;

        return '</form>';
    }
```